# How can I make a overhead a method with the parameter HashMap?

Tags: java

I have two methods that make the same thing, but one receives a `HashMap<Integer,double[]>` and the other receive a `HashMap<Integer,int[]>`. How can I make this without to duplicate code.

Comment: You could convert to `Map<Integer,Number[]>`, but that would involve changing callers of the method and Object overhead. Guess, there's no better way, though.

Comment: The code you posted won't even compile, you need to use `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`

Comment: @msrd0 Why should this not compile?

Comment: @msrd0 a primitive array is an `Object`, and thus eligible as a type argument. It compiles just fine.

Comment: @qqilihq Because Java doesn't allow types like `int` or `double` to be templates. You always need the wrapper classes like `Integer` or `Double`

Comment: @msrd0 Not true. Arrays are Objects.

Comment: @Mureinik Really? Thought this causes an error ...

Comment: I'm gonna try replace Map<Integer,double[]> for Map<Integer,Number[]>.

Answer (score 0):

Make two methods, one contains the real code, acception the version with the double-array and the other method, accepting the integer-version just calls this method but first converts the integer-array to a double array.

```
public void doSomething(HashMap<Integer, int[]> arg0) {

   //convert int[] to double[] and fill this HashMap
   HashMap<Integer, double[]> converted;

   doSomething(converted);
}

public void doSomething(HashMap<Integer, double[]> arg0) {

   //your logic here

}
```

Comment: this won't work because of erasure both become `doSomething(HashMap<Object,Object> arg0)` at runtime!

Comment: yes, noticed after posting. thank you for alerting me to that fact.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Could I to make this with generics types ?

Comment: this will never work!`doStuff(HashMap<Integer,double[]>) and doStuff(HashMap<Integer,int[]>) have the same erasure`